# Liferay 7 - product menu customization

Tags: java, liferay, overriding, portlet

I'm trying to customize product menu in Liferay 7 (==== sucks ====)

Steps: 
I create (maven) template project. 
Overriding category class to reference to ROOT.

But my custom panel app isn't showing as submenu. Do you know why?

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "panel.category.key=" + PanelCategoryKeys.ROOT,
        "panel.category.order:Integer=200"
    },
    service = PanelCategory.class
)
public class SamplePanelCategory extends BasePanelCategory {

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return SamplePanelCategoryKeys.CONTROL_PANEL_CATEGORY;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel(Locale locale) {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundleUtil.getBundle(
            "content.Language", locale, getClass());

        return LanguageUtil.get(resourceBundle, "category.custom.label");
    }}


@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "panel.app.order:Integer=100",
        "panel.category.key=" + SamplePanelCategoryKeys.CONTROL_PANEL_CATEGORY
    },
    service = PanelApp.class
)
public class SamplePanelApp extends BasePanelApp {

    @Override
    public String getPortletId() {
        return SamplePortletKeys.Sample;
    }

    @Override
    @Reference(
        target = "(javax.portlet.name=" + SamplePortletKeys.Sample + ")",
        unbind = "-"
    )
    public void setPortlet(Portlet portlet) {
        super.setPortlet(portlet);
    }

}
```

If i change the SamplePanelApp (panel.category.key) to something from Liferay Keys (PanelCategoryKeys) it will work.

Thx

P.S.: in tutorial they recomanded to override include method to show the body of my custom category... but i'm unable to find how (some kind of example)

Thx.

Comment: As i'm progressing i found that bnd file is important too. It contains target symbolic name.